# database modeling - column with same behavior but different type of data

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to modeling a system inside standard SQL database and I have the following situation.

I have table that should store source location. But there is 3 kind of locations: `URI`, `FileSystem Path`, `ID` (for external service).

Thus first implementation was something like

```
table my_table (
  id ...,
  uri VARCHAR(2083),
  path VARCHAR(255),
  ext_id VARCHAR(255)
)
```

This implementation has a drawbacks:

- Cannot constraint NOT NULL (when using basic SGBD like MySQL)

To resolve (try) this problem I add a hash field:

```
table my_table (
  id ...,
  uri VARCHAR(2083),
  path VARCHAR(255),
  ext_id VARCHAR(255),
  hash CHAR(32) NOT NULL
)
```

that represents a `hash(uri)`, `hash(path)` or `hash(ext_id)` and in addition will help to index `uri` (indexing `VARCHAR(2083)` seems to be not possible or not efficient)

Other solution is to merge all location inside one column like following

```
table my_table (
  id ...,
  location VARCHAR(2083) NOT NULL,
  type INT(2) NOT NULL,
  hash CHAR(32)
)
```

That resolves *not null issues* but we must used `VARCHAR(2083)` and adding `type` information as discriminator...

I know both solutions are not **normalized** but performance is a priority. This table will be heavily used (80% read - 20% write).

Any advices?

PS: I can't use any specific database vendor features or triggers/stored procedures.

---

**EDIT: Chosen solution:**

```
table my_table (
  id ...,
  location VARCHAR(255),
  type SMALLINT
)
```

- How can you manage URI longer than 255?

After data analysis I find URI longer than 255 is really rare case. My actual data model (before this new model) store URI on `VARCHAR(255)` so no regression for me.

I plan to implement an url shortener service to manage the 1% of case where URI > 255.

I don't want to handicap 99% of common usage for 1% of use case.

- Why not keeping `VARCHAR(2083)` anyway?

One reason is *MySQL* engine cannot set `UNIQUE constraint` on `VARCHAR(2083)`.

- Why did you delete hash field?

I think (maybe it's wrong) `VARCHAR(255)` index is enough and all databases vendor should manage it correctly.

Comment: I see two possibilities, the first is that you use separate table for URIs, files and IDs and JOIN them with the one you have, the second is that you may set a trigger to not allow to set three NULL values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Merging all columns seem to be fine. You can use a reference table for the type of location used. So you can have typeid in your merged table, and the location will be populated irrespective of the type of the location. Not sure how much of an advantage you are getting out of the hash though.

table my_table (
  id ...,
  location VARCHAR(2083) NOT NULL,
  typeId INT(1) NOT NULL --> FK reference to location_Type
)

table location_Type (
typeId INT(1) NOT NULL,
typeName VARCHAR(100) NOT NULL
)

Also forgot to answer your doubt about using VARCHAR(2003). a VARCHAR column is variable length column. So when you create a column as VARCHAR(50) and populate it with a value of “ABC” only 5 bytes are stored, 2 byte for the length of the data, plus 3 bytes for the value “ABC”. So it won't take up extra space.

Comment: Yeah I know about extra space, but I really don't know how database engine manage data fragmentation or allocation even using dynamic type like `VARCHAR`.

Comment: Is the db large? If not, maybe try use `CHAR` type @Kakawait

Comment: db should be around >=10 go (whole db no just the table we are talking)

Comment: Considering that you are mostly using it for querying and not updating frequently, fragmentation should not be an issue. the extra overhead in maintaining variable length columns is generally minimal as far as i know.

Comment: @Voitcus, CHAR should not be used as it will end up eating more space incase the location is just 255 characters.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1631175/does-varchar-result-in-performance-hit-due-to-data-fragmentation. See if this helps you

Comment: @Kakawait, please share your answer with us if you get one and mark the answer as correct if you think its right.

Comment: Yeah don't worry, I was debating the subject with other colleagues. I think I will merge all in one field `location` plus I try to negotiate to reduce size to 500. I really think url larger than 500 chars will be rare and we can manage it with url shortener!

Comment: @Pratik After long discussion I edit my post to add my final solution.